# Pivot Table filter not Changing to each value in Loop

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I've seen a lot of similar posts but none of them have been able to fix my issue with changing a pivot table filter field.  I'm trying to filter through a loop that takes each value in the list on ws2 and pastes changes the `FilterID` to that value.  However in all the different methods I've tried, setting it to a value, setting it to a string, using `"CurrentPage"`, none of them have worked or resulted in a 1004 error.  My latest effort is below.  How can I get the `"MatchFilter"` to change based on the value in my loop below ?

The method below just gives a 1004 Application or object not defined error.

I also tried to add `MatchFilter.Orientation = xlPageField` but no success.

```
Sub Filter_Test()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Sheets("Order_Groupings")

'The match list is the list of unique Match IDs to filter through, pasting each in the filter
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws2 = Sheets("Match_List")

'Here we will paste the results from each optimizer run
Dim ws3 As Worksheet
Set ws3 = Sheets("Optimizer_Results")

Dim pt As PivotTable
Set pt = ws1.PivotTables("Order_Groupings")

Dim FilterID As String

Dim MatchFilter As PivotField
Set MatchFilter = pt.PivotFields("Match_ID")

Dim numIDs As Integer

'This is the number of different match IDs
'Match count is set to J4 right now in the Match List tab
numIDs = ws2.Range("match_count").Value

'For loop to cycle through each Match ID
For i = 1 To numIDs
    
    FilterID = ws2.Range("A4").Offset(i, 0).Value
    
    'Trying to set the MatchFilter to the new value in FilterID
    With MatchFilter
        .ClearAllFilters
        .CurrentPageName = FilterID
    End With

Next i
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up working by clearing all the filters beforehand and using PivotFilter.Add Type:=xlCpationEquals

```
Sub Filter_Test()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Sheets("Order_Groupings")

'The match list is the list of unique Match IDs to filter through, pasting each in the filter
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws2 = Sheets("Match_List")

'Here we will paste the results from each optimizer run
Dim ws3 As Worksheet
Set ws3 = Sheets("Optimizer_Results")

Dim pt As PivotTable
Set pt = ws1.PivotTables("Order_Groupings")

Dim FilterID As String

Dim MatchFilter As PivotField
Set MatchFilter = pt.PivotFields("Match_IDs")

Dim numIDs As Integer

Dim i As Integer

'This is the number of different match IDs
'Match count is set to J4 right now in the Match List tab
numIDs = ws2.Range("match_count").Value

'For loop to cycle through each Match ID
For i = 1 To numIDs
    
    FilterID = ws2.Range("A4").Offset(i, 0)
    
    MatchFilter.ClearAllFilters

    MatchFilter.PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionEquals, Value1:=FilterID

Next i
    
End Sub
```